# How to change image on selected row of table view

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

i want to change image on seleted row of tableview.
and all the other images on other rows remain same. when any other row is selected then image gets change for that row and first one comes back to original image.
plzz provide a demo solution.

Comment: Start with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: what to do in that ..?? plz expain that